# Comparing many Correlations in R

Tags: r, correlation, confidence-interval, pearson-correlation

I have hundreds of correlations of populations (varying species, locations, etc) over time. How can I statistically analyze all these correlations (for their respective groups)?

I have p-values, CIs, correlation coefficients for each of the 600+ correlations, but how can I compare these within groups (species, location, etc).

I have tried to perform large partial correlations on the data correlating population number (in percent) and year, with species and location (turned into dummy variables) as controlled factors when correlating within Families, and with location (as dummy variable) as a controlled variable when correlating within species but am not sure if that is correct.

Here is some sample data, but this is a more logistic question oppose to actual data issue:

```
Location    Species                 Year    Section Total   Percent Family
Chiswell A  Black-legged Kittiwake  1976    Central 310 16.78397401 Gull
Chiswell A  Black-legged Kittiwake  1986    Central 982 53.16729832 Gull
Chiswell A  Black-legged Kittiwake  1989    Central 555 30.04872767 Gull
Chiswell B  Common Murre            1976    Central 150 20.6043956  Auk
Chiswell B  Common Murre            1986    Central 385 52.88461538 Auk
Chiswell B  Common Murre            1991    Central 193 26.51098901 Auk
Natoa Is    Black-legged Kittiwake  1976    Central 70  12.77372263 Gull
Natoa Is    Black-legged Kittiwake  1986    Central 168 30.65693431 Gull
Natoa Is    Black-legged Kittiwake  1989    Central 310 56.56934307 Gull
Wooded Is   Black-legged Kittiwake  1972    Central 1560    13.35159192 Gull
Wooded Is   Pelagic Cormorant       1972    Central 144 45.56962025 Cormorant
Wooded Is   Black-legged Kittiwake  1976    Central 2350    20.11297501 Gull
Wooded Is   Glaucous-winged Gull    1976    Central 150 13.83763838 Gull
Wooded Is   Horned Puffin           1976    Central 30  33.33333333 Auk
Wooded Is   Pelagic Cormorant       1976    Central 44  13.92405063 Cormorant
Wooded Is   Pigeon Guillemot        1976    Central 100 37.59398496 Auk
Wooded Is   Red-faced Cormorant     1976    Central 4   66.66666667 Cormorant
Wooded Is   Tufted Puffin           1976    Central 9600    98.21976673 Auk
Wooded Is   Black-legged Kittiwake  2000    Central 5587    47.81752824 Gull
Wooded Is   Glaucous-winged Gull    2000    Central 472 43.54243542 Gull
Wooded Is   Horned Puffin           2000    Central 30  33.33333333 Auk
Wooded Is   Pelagic Cormorant       2000    Central 64  20.25316456 Cormorant
Wooded Is   Pigeon Guillemot        2000    Central 83  31.20300752 Auk
Wooded Is   Red-faced Cormorant     2000    Central 1   16.66666667 Cormorant
Wooded Is   Tufted Puffin           2000    Central 87  0.890116636 Auk
Wooded Is   Black-legged Kittiwake  2001    Central 2187    18.71790483 Gull
Wooded Is   Glaucous-winged Gull    2001    Central 462 42.6199262  Gull
Wooded Is   Horned Puffin           2001    Central 30  33.33333333 Auk
Wooded Is   Pelagic Cormorant       2001    Central 64  20.25316456 Cormorant
Wooded Is   Pigeon Guillemot        2001    Central 83  31.20300752 Auk
Wooded Is   Red-faced Cormorant     2001    Central 1   16.66666667 Cormorant
Wooded Is   Tufted Puffin           2001    Central 87  0.890116636 Auk
```

Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired output is.  Maybe a sample table?

Comment: @pyll my desired output would be an "comprehensive" correlation of a species within a Section or within a family. I have performed a correlation just with a species subset (i.e. tufted puffin) of percent and year, but this does not account for location, so although I have a corcoeff, p-value, etc, for that species across the whole sampling area, I don't think it is statistically correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is out of the scope of a stack overflow question and should probably be posted in a more statistically oriented forum.

However, I would check out the `vegan` package and specifically look at Canonical Correspondence analysis or Principal component analysis.  Ordination methods like allow you to reduce the dimensionality and look at the significant/useful correlations among many different grouping variables.

[Vegan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vignettes/intro-vegan.pdf)

## Update

With a time series as one of the variables in the model, it would be statistically correct to determine if there are effects related to the repeated collections through time.  A multi-way ANOVA may be more useful in determining correlation between variables than finding groups of points in an ordination method.

Comment: I agree, but there is much more traffic here in Stack overflow compared to other stats forums. I have worked in Vegan before with NMDS analyses. I'm not sure if this applies to this however, I will check it out again.

Comment: NMDS are pretty limited IMO, but you could use another ordination method to understand the significant grouping variables.  As another method, you could always create a general linear from the count data with a quasi-Poisson distribution, for all grouping variables and use an f-test to determine significance from the p-value.

Comment: I tried the GLM but I don't think it is what I'm looking for. I'm also unsure if PCA or CCA are what I'm looking for either. Basically I'm just trying to see if populations have changed over time for species at varying populations within a Large geographic area, but I don't know how to do this aside from performing 600 correlations, which I have done. I suppose I can just show what percent of populations for each species is declining/increasing, would that be statistically valid?
Is there a more comprehensive way?

Comment: If there is a time variable, you may want to determine if there are any significant time effects (time series analysis........ugh). 
As for *the populations that have changed over time etc...*, there you could use something like an anova on [repeated measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62756/2x2x5-repeated-measures-anova-significant-3-way-interaction) to determine if you have sig interaction or look at [mixed models](http://ase.tufts.edu/gsc/gradresources/guidetomixedmodelsinr/mixed%20model%20guide.html) that may better fit your initial question of finding sig corrrelation.